# Returning the value of a hash stores inside a set in redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm new to Redis... like 30 minutes new, and I'm using the node-redis package to build a web app. 
From what I see the best data structure to use to store a webpage's data would be a hash, but I also need to keep track of which webpages I have across the whole app. So this is what I'm doing :

```
//this is in Redis-CLI
//add the page and it's data to a hash
HMSET pages:/myurl url /myurl title myTitle description myDescription content myContent lang_mirror /frenchurl

//then I add the page to my set
sadd pages pages:/myurl
```

Now I want to return the values inside pages:/myurl, is there a single call to the set that can do this for me? Or something built into node-redis that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using the command [HGETALL](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall), like so:

```
HGETALL pages:/myurl
```

**Edited based on comment:**
Ah, so look at [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) but mind its complexity and memory footprint:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET pages:/myurl url /myurl title myTitle description myDescription content myContent lang_mirror /frenchurl
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD pages pages:/myurl
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SORT pages BY nosort GET *->url GET *->title GET *->description GET *->content GET *->lang_mirror
1) "/myurl"
2) "myTitle"
3) "myDescription"
4) "myContent"
5) "/frenchurl"
```

Attentively, you could look into using Lua server-side scripting for this.

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't do what I need. I need to be able to get all of my hashes, like pages:/myurl, pages:/myurl2, pages:/myurl3 etc in one call, that's why I wanted to put all my pages hashes into a set.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make 2 calls at least, one to get the members of the set and then another one to get all the hashes, here is some sample code using node-redis.

```
redis.smembers('pages', function(err, pages) {
    var multi = redis.multi();
    for(var i=0; i<pages.length; ++i) {
        multi.hgetall(pages[i]);
    }

    multi.exec(function(err, pageData) {
         console.log(pageData);
    });
});
```